# Permutation of word

Tags: permutations, self-learning

**Question:**

Find the permutation of letters of the word **EXERCISES** in which vowels are together.

**My Efforts:**

I have rearranged the word in such a way that all the vowel come together.

EEEI XRCSS

Now the vowels can be arranged in $\frac{4!}{3!}$(E is repeated 3 times) ways and remaining letters can be arranged in $\frac{4!}{2!}$(S is repeated 2 times) ways.

Further above shown arrangement can be permuted in $2!$ ways(Consonant can be written first and then vowel.)

So total permutation possible $$\frac{4!}{3!} \times \frac{4!}{2!} \times 2! = 96 $$

But the answer given is $1440$  is is far more than mine, I am surely missing something.

Comment: Isn't there only one S?

Comment: @MickA Thanks for noticing. Sorry that was typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes I believe.

First of all, there are $5$ remaining letters so there can be $\dfrac{5!}{2!}$ arrangements, and not $\dfrac{4!}{2!}$.

Secondly, the vowels need to be together, not the other letters. For example, S EEEI XRCS is legit. There can be $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ or $5$ letters before the vowels, so you need to multiply the final result by $6$, not $2$.

The final calculation gives $\dfrac{4!}{3!} \times \dfrac{5!}{2!} \times 6 = 1440$.